# Selenium Web Driver How to Click Span Class Element

Tags: selenium, webdriver, classname

```js
<span class="title ng-binding">TEST</span>
```

ı want to click the following.
I ve tried lots of ways but did not success. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Comment: I  use Java @DebanjanB. Actually there is a left side bar menu which made by Angular and i want to click a page inside the menu.

Comment: when i try the "new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.title.ng-binding"))).click(); " the action is just opening the menu. ı can not click the page.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following (**Java**) solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.title.ng-binding"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='title ng-binding' and contains(.,'TEST')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: @MuhammetAltunbaş To comment or ask a counter question with respect to my Answer you must ask through a comment below my Answer only, else I don't get notified.

Comment: @MuhammetAltunbaş If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.